# Using MIB tables with Prometheus and SNMP Exporter

Tags: snmp, prometheus

I am using Prometheus with SNMP exporter to scrape metrics from a large network of PoS systems.  I am using the generator, with UCD-SNMP-MIB from NetSNMP (as referenced on the SNMP Exporter webpage).

One of the metrics I see is load.  According to the MIB, it is in a table called laLoad.  When I scrape this MIB, I get unexpected results in Prometheus:

```
laLoad{instance="boston01",job="poc",laIndex="1",laLoad="1.43"}
```

My load is there, as a label.  That goes for the 1, 5, and 15m loads (which are in different metrics.  The metric value themselves (for the time series) are always 1.

How can I use MIB tables with SNMP Exporter / Prometheus (load doesn't seem available in Linux MIBs, as scalers, in a way that Prometheus will recognize)?

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest here to use `laLoadFloat` if your devices support it, as recent versions of the SNMP exporter added opaque float support.

Answer (score 0):

"use laLoadFloat": This method you mentioned needs to be modified when SNMP generates information. It would be better if you can modify it in snmp_exporter.